# Setting a parent's state to a child's state setter

Tags: reactjs

I have the following React example, where I'm setting a state to the value of another state setter.

```
import React, {
  Dispatch,
  SetStateAction,
  useEffect,
  useState,
} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const A = ({}) => {
  const [setStage, setStageSetter] = useState<Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('A.setStage', setStage);

    if (setStage) {
      setStage(2);
    }
  }, [setStage, setStageSetter]);

  return <B setStageSetter={setStageSetter} />;
};

const B = ({ setStageSetter }) => {
  const [stage, setStage] = useState<number>(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('B.setStage', setStage);

    setStageSetter(setStage);
  }, [setStage, setStageSetter]);

  return <p>{stage}</p>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<A />, mountNode);
```

However, when I run the above, it does not output what I'd expect, which is for the above to read `2` in the DOM. It seems to set the value to `1`, and then to `undefined` Why is this?

---

A solution to the above is the following answer:

```
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const B = ({ setStageSetter }) => {
  const [stage, setStage] = useState(1);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setStageSetter(() => setStage);
  }, [setStage, setStageSetter]);

  return <p>{stage}</p>;
};

const A = () => {
  const [setStage, setStageSetter] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (setStage) {
      setStage(2);
    }
  }, [setStage]);

  return <B setStageSetter={setStageSetter} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<A />, mountNode);
```

The functional difference is from `setStageSetter(setStage);` to `setStageSetter(() => setStage);`

Whilst this does set the parent's state to the setter of the child, and I can call a method in the parent and set the child's state, I don't understand why the callback is required. Why is this? Is this "bad practice"?

Comment: @helrabelo I think you've misunderstood what the intent of `setStageSetter` is. It is used to set the stage setter, not the stage itself. i.e., its parameter type is `Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>`, not `number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `setStageSetter` call was invoked with a different parameter, it seems to have achieved the desired objective. Please see the code snippet below for a working demo.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const {
  Dispatch,
  SetStateAction,
  useEffect,
  useState
} = React;

const B = ({ setStageSetter }) => {
  const [stage, setStage] = useState(1);
// <Number>
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('B stage: ', stage, ' setStage', setStage);
    // calling the props method with a "function" and not the setter as-is
    setStageSetter(() => setStage);
  }, [setStage, setStageSetter]);

  return <p>{stage}</p>;
};

const A = ({}) => {
  const [setStageA, setStageSetter] = useState(()=>{});
// <Dispatch<SetStateAction<Number>>
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('A setStageA', setStageA);

    if (setStageA) {      // to realize the change on screen, delay by 1.5 seconds
      setTimeout(() => setStageA(2), 1500);
      // setStageA(2); // this works too, but change is not immediately observable
    }
  }, [setStageA, setStageSetter]);

  return <B setStageSetter={setStageSetter} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    DEMO
    <A />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("rd")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="rd" />
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added to the snippet above.

Comment: Interesting! So changing `setStageSetter(setStage)` to `setStageSetter(() => setStage)` seems to be the change that solves the issue. Any idea why using that callback changes the behaviour here?

Comment: Hopefully someone from this community enlightens both of us - as I'm also interested to learn.